# Pulling multiple elements out of an array and labeling them specifically

Tags: java, arrays

I need to program an array that functions as horses in a race. Everytime the user presses `enter` the horses will "run" or the array will add random numbers to them and update their position. The console is printing their position after every button press. I need to label the 1st 2nd and 3rd horses after the race is over (when the horses hit 15). I cannot figure out how to do this.

Right now I am searching through the array and if an element of the array is greater than or equal to 15 I have it set to print the first place horse. How do I make it so that it will print the 2nd and 3rd place as the next highest positions (ex. 1st = 15, 2nd = 13, 3rd = 12)?

Also, it appears that my program will not stop. How do I get it to stop after 15 or higher is reached? Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class HorseRace2{
  public static void main(String[ ] arg){
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   int range = 3;
   int win = 15;
   final int SIZE = 3;
   Random ran = new Random( );
   boolean winner = false; 
   int[ ] arrRan = new int[SIZE];


    System.out.print("Off to the races! Press enter to make the horses run.");

    String readString = reader.nextLine();
    while(readString!=null){
      System.out.print(readString);
      if(readString.equals("")){
         for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){
            arrRan[i] = arrRan[i] + (ran.nextInt(3) + 1); 
            System.out.println("Horse " + (i+1) + ":" + arrRan[i]);
         }   

      }//end if

      if(reader.hasNextLine()){
         readString = reader.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please press enter to make the horses run.");
      }
      for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){
         if(arrRan[i]>=win){
            System.out.println("1st place: Horse " + (i+1));
         }
      }
    }//end while


   }//close main
}//close class
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not stopping because the condition `readString != null` isn't being violated.

For it to print the non-1st place horses, sort the array and assign places as applicable.

For it to stop, try replacing `while( readString != null )` with `while( nobodyHasWon )`. Make a boolean `boolean nobodyHasWon = true` and set it to false when a horse has won (i.e., after `System.out.println("1st place: Horse " + (i+1));`).

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
// assumptions made: there is only one winner at 15, the rest are below 15, there are no ties, and the first ranked horse has been found
int second, third, secondValue, thirdValue;
secondValue = 0; thirdValue = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < arrRan.length; i++ ) {
    if( i != <indexOfFirstPlaceHorse> )
    {
    if( arrRan[ i ] > secondValue ) {
        second = i;
        secondValue = arrRan[ i ];
    }
    }
}
for( int i = 0; i < arrRan.length; i++ ) {
    if( i != <indexOfFirstPlaceHorse> && i != second ) {
        if( arrRan[ i ] > thirdValue ) {
            third = i;
            thirdValue = arrRan[ i ];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After sorting the array how do I get it to print the first three horses?

Comment: Since you've sorted the array, you now have a ranking for the horses' progress. Keep in mind that the labelling of your horses will be messed up because the indices have been switched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I updated the code.

[SEE DEMO](https://ideone.com/XDFyIW)

```
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
   int range = 3;
   int win = 15;
   final int SIZE = 3;
   Random ran = new Random( );
   boolean winner = false; 
   int[ ] arrRan = new int[SIZE];


    System.out.print("Off to the races! Press enter to make the horses run.");

    String readString = reader.nextLine();
    while(readString!=null){
        if(!winner){
          System.out.print(readString);
          if(readString.equals("")){
             for(int i = 0; i<arrRan.length; i++){
                arrRan[i] = arrRan[i] + (ran.nextInt(3) + 1); 
                System.out.println("Horse " + (i+1) + ":" + arrRan[i]);
             }   

          }//end if

          for(int j = 0; j<arrRan.length; j++){
             if(arrRan[j]>=win){
                winner =true;
                }
             }


          if(reader.hasNextLine()){
             readString = reader.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Please press enter to make the horses run.");
          }
        }else{
            int[] arrClone = new int[arrRan.length];
            for(int i=0;i<arrRan.length;i++){
                arrClone[i] = arrRan[i];
            }

            arrRan = sortArray(arrRan);
            int[] arrRank = new int[arrRan.length];
            int prevNum = arrRan.length;

            for(int i=0;i<arrRan.length;i++){
                boolean flag = true;
                for(int j=0;j<arrRan.length;j++){
                    if(arrRan[i]==arrClone[j]){
                        if(j!=prevNum && flag){
                                prevNum = j;
                                arrRank[i] = j+1;
                                flag=false;
                        }                                     
                    }                                
                }

            }
            System.out.println("1st place: Horse " + (arrRank[0]));
            System.out.println("2nd place: Horse " + (arrRank[1]));
            System.out.println("3rd place: Horse " + (arrRank[2]));
            break;
        }
    }//end while

    }
    public static int[] sortArray (int[] inArray)
{

    //Construct the array we're using here
    int[] newArray = inArray;

    for(int x = 0; x < newArray.length; x++) //a.length = # of indices in the array
    {

        for(int y = 0; y < newArray.length; y++)
        {
            if(newArray[x] > newArray [y]) {
                int tempValue = newArray[y];
                newArray[y] = newArray[x];
                newArray[x] = tempValue;
            }
        }

    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Hey this is exactly what I was looking for. One thing though, the console prints 1st Place: Horse 15. The problem I had was that it would print the position of the horse (15) rather than the horse number (1st Place: Horse X).

Comment: Got it. Try that one.